# How to divide sections of UITableView by Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, date, tableview

I have a TableView divided into cell. The text of the cell is fireDate to UILocalNotification. This is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    cellView *cell = (cellView *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *localnotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [localnotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:localNotification.fireDate];
    [cell.textlabel setText:timeString];
    return cell;
}
```

How to can I create section divided by date?

Comment: This seems similar to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053741/ios-uitableview-sections-based-on-date-ranges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First your section numbers must be the count of the array

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
      // Return the number of sections.
      return [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]count];
  }

> The number of rows must be one per section

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}
```

> Here give a name for each section i dont know the structure of your
>   array but if its a dictionary for example : objectForKey:@"date"...

```
- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications] objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

> In cellForRowAtIndexPath first check the indexPath.section and set
>   your object like you usually do with one section

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case indexPath.row:
       // fill your cell // 
        default:
        break;
    }

}
```

I don't have a computer near me to test I'm telling you this by memory's i hope at least you got the idea how tableView work.

All best and good luck.

Comment: That's perfect,the code works!But the problema is that when 2 notifications have the same date it create two section.How can i do to create a section with 2 notifications with the same date?